# Snmp agent implementation in c++ builder plus indy

Tags: c++builder, snmp, indy

I have a c++ application which uses Indy components for TCP communications.
Now I need to implement SNMP agent (?) just in order to respond requests
about application's state via SNMP.
I decided to use Indy components for this task too.
Maybe there is some standart way to implement this?

SNMP component to get some values works pretty well. 
But I couldn't find some example how to return values from my application via snmp.

As advised by Remy Lebeau I've started implementing SendTrap.

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::btSendTrapClick(TObject *Sender)
{
UnicodeString myEnterprise   = "1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5";
UnicodeString eventType      = "1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5.1";
UnicodeString eventDistance  = "1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5.2";

TIdSNMP * idSnmp = 0;
TSNMPInfo * infoSnmp = 0;

idSnmp                 = new TIdSNMP(NULL);
infoSnmp               = new TSNMPInfo(idSnmp);

idSnmp->Host           = edHost->Text;
idSnmp->Community      = "public";

infoSnmp->Host           = edHost->Text;
infoSnmp->Community      = "public";
infoSnmp->Enterprise = myEnterprise;
infoSnmp->GenTrap = 6;                       // I've met such values
infoSnmp->SpecTrap = 1;                      // somewhere in inet
infoSnmp->MIBAdd(eventType,"ftCritical");
infoSnmp->MIBAdd(eventDistance,"2.357");

idSnmp->SendTrap();

delete idSnmp;
}
```

But when I run application there is no udp activity in my system.
When I run something like this

```
idSnmp->QuickSend(sysDescr, "public", edHost->Text, val);
```

wireshark shows
  192.168.100.21    192.168.100.19  SNMP    82  get-request 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0

but when `idSnmp->SendTrap()` wireshark sees nothing
(filter for wireshark is UDP portrange 161-162 in both cases)

I'll be glad to see some remarks about my code or maybe working example of SendTrap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indy does not have an SNMP server component.  To allow apps to request SNMP values from your app, you would have to implement your own SNMP server, such as by using `TIdUDPServer` and its `OnUDPRead` event and then parse the SNMP requests manually.

Another option would be to have external apps register themselves with your app, and then your app could use `TIdSNMP.SendTrap()` to push status updates to registered apps when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are simply not seeing traps leaving your host. I see this was a while ago, but this works for me... paraphrasing my code a bit:

```
void SendTrap(int atcsfield)
{
TIdSNMP *snmp = new TIdSNMP(0);
    snmp->Trap->Clear();
    snmp->Trap->Version = 2;
    snmp->Trap->Community=String(cfg.snmp.community);
    snmp->Trap->TimeTicks = GetTickCount() - InitialTickCount;
    snmp->Trap->Enterprise=String(cfg.snmp.oid);
    snmp->Trap->GenTrap=6;
    snmp->Trap->SpecTrap=1;
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_VARBINDS;i++)
    {
        if(svb[i].Length())
        {
            varb.sprintf("%s.1.%d",BaseOID.c_str(),i);
            snmp->Trap->MIBAdd(varb,svb[i], ASN1_OCTSTR);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_VARBINDS;i++)
    {
        if(ivb[i]!=-1)
        {
            varb.sprintf("%s.1.%d",BaseOID.c_str(),i);
            snmp->Trap->MIBAdd(varb, ivb[i], ASN1_INT);
        }
    }
    snmp->Host = ManagerIpList->Strings[j];
    snmp->SendTrap();
}
```

I found that the Clear() is required for every time you send a trap. In working code, I instantiate the TIdSNMP component, then make calls to SendTrap().  I have three IP targets and must call Clear() to send a trap to each one.

HTH